# inOut String is not convertible to String

Tags: swift

I have a function that return the st or th matching the dates. I now want to return the month with it as well. The month is printing correctly, but when I try to add it in case it throws this error, inOutString is not convertible to String.

```
if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: date)
    {

        let monthString: String = dateFormatterMonthPrint.string(from: date)

        print("This is month Str: \(monthString)")

        var dateString = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date)

        switch (dateString) {

        case "1" , "21" , "31":  dateString.append("st") + "," + "\(monthString)"

        case "2" , "22": dateString.append("nd")

        case "3" ,"23": dateString.append("rd")

        default: dateString.append("th")
        }

        return dateString
    }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use Calendar and DateComponents, should be easier. Also, you could use NumberFormatter with `.ordinal` option for style to add st, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
case "1" , "21" , "31":  dateString.append("st") + "," + "\(monthString)"
```

`dateString.append` does *not* return a value. It only mutates (changes) `dateString`. This means that you can use this method in an expression expecting a `String`.

Swift has string interpolation, so you don't need these `+` things at all, and `append` can be replaced by the `+=` operator:

```
case "1" , "21" , "31":  dateString += "st, \(mothString)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this, you dont need to use append

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just move the closing parentheses to the end of the line to concatenate the literal strings before appending the result and creating a string from a string with String Interpolation is redundant

```
case "1" , "21" , "31":  dateString.append("st, " + monthString)
```

Note:

Rather than using (multiple) date formatters to get date components from a date use `Calendar` and `DateComponents`. That's much more efficient for example

```
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month], from: date)
let day = components.day!
let month = components.month!
```

Both values are `Int`